# onConfigurationChanged does not work while change orientation

Tags: android

THe manaifest.xml of activity as below:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.wd.wuc.SearchStatusActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="sensor"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"  >
</activity>
```

The Activity's code as below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_status);
    System.out.println("onCreate!!");
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    System.out.println("onConfigurationChanged!!");
}
```

While I change orientation, I want to run onConfigurationChanged.
But the code only run onCreate method, but not onConfigurationChanged.
How can I modify it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html), you can find:

```
If your application targets API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), then you should also declare the "screenSize" configuration, because it also changes when a device switches between portrait and landscape orientations.
```

You should try to add "|screenSize" to configChanges if you are targeting API 13 or higher:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
```

Answer (score 1):

`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"`

this line tells Dalvik compiler that you are handling changes of keyboard and Orientation.so kindly remove this line it will work for sure.

Comment: if we are handling then why onCreate() is getting called ?

Comment: if you are not writing this line in manifest it means that config changes will be handled by dalvik VM.so it will restart the activity.and so oncrete is getting called.if you don't want to be called it all the time and you don't want your activity to be reinitialized thaen you have to write this line in manifest.sorry for bad English.

Comment: i didn't ask this, i am saying even if he has written this line, he is saying onCreate() is getting called. So why it is getting called again ?

Comment: OnCreate will only be called if you have not written this line in manifest.

Comment: see his question man. Even if he has written this code, onCreate() is getting called not the onConfigurationChanged() ?

Comment: he didn't mention that oncreate is called second time..may be he wants to say that it called for first time only..because it isn't possible that oncreate is called.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
```

with

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

in your manifest file.

Look [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

remove this from manifest file this tag. then it will work

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
```